# Как конвертировать большой Json файл в XML?

Tags: python

Понадобилось конвертировать большой json файл(300 000 строк) в xml.

Однако при попытке чтения файла и переноса того в xml с помощью dicttoxml у меня выходит ошибка Memory error.

```
with open('file.json', 'r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
xml = dicttoxml.dicttoxml(data)
with open('xml.xml', 'w') as f:
    f.write(xml)
```

На компьютере 16 гб озу но все равно не понимаю в чем проблема, так что задал вопрос сюда

Сам вопрос - Каким образом можно беспроблемно перевести большой json файл в xml?

## EDIT

Строка в json файле выглядит так:

```
{"Big Images": ["/path/to/image1.jpg", "/path/to/image2.jpg"], "Title": ["Some Title"], "Summary": ["(Здесь либо пусто либо текстовое описание)"], "Price": ["99.9"], "Color": ["", "", "", "COD", "Multi", "50 x 80cm"], "Main Info": ["В среднем 30-50 строк кода"]}
```

Все строки одинаковые(кроме внутренностей но они тоже кроме слов и цифер одинаковые)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97098/discussion-on-question-by-mark----json---xml).

Comment: Каждая строка json - это отдельный блок, не связанный с содержанием остального файла? Если да, тогда пробуйте конвертировать не весь массив, а построчно.

Comment: собственно сейчас я над этим работаю =(

Comment: Сейчас застрял на том - как во после считывания 1 строки в file.json конвертировать сразу записать в xml.xml

Comment: Вроде получилось! из 1.1 гб json файла вышел 700 мб xml файл. Только вот выглядит он странно - куча пробелов и непонятных стилей / каким-то образом в json файле появились неизвестно откуда теги <table>

Comment: Приведите код, который помог решить проблему, в ответе - это поможет другим пользователям, которые столнулись с похожей проблемой